# When and why did "No man is an island" start being regarded as a poem?

Tags: poetry, textual-history, essays, john-donne, devotions-upon-emergent-occasions

John Donne's "[Meditation XVII](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Meditation_XVII)" from *[Devotions upon Emergent Occasions](https://archive.org/details/devotionsuponeme00donn/page/n5/mode/2up)* (1624) includes the following well-known passage:

> No man is an island, entire of itself; every man is a piece of the continent, a part of the main. If a clod be washed away by the sea, Europe is the less, as well as if a promontory were, as well as if a manor of thy friend's or of thine own were: any man's death diminishes me, because I am involved in mankind, and therefore never send to know for whom the bell tolls; it tolls for thee.

*Devotions* was, and is, a prose work. It was published as prose during Donne's lifetime, and continues to be printed as prose in [modern scholarly editions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0375705481). Currently, however, this passage circulates as poetry. The top results of an [online search](https://lmgtfy.app/#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=no%20man%20is%20an%20island) for "No man is an island" do not include any that have the entire text of Meditation XVII. Instead, they surface several sites that present this one passage as a poem, with the lines broken up as follows:

> No man is an island,
> Entire of itself;
> Every man is a piece of the continent,
> A part of the main.
>
> If a clod be washed away by the sea,
> Europe is the less,
> As well as if a promontory were:
> As well as if a manor of thy friend's
> Or of thine own were.
>
> Any man's death diminishes me,
> Because I am involved in mankind.
> And therefore never send to know for whom the bell tolls;
> It tolls for thee.

Examples:

- [All Poetry](https://allpoetry.com/No-man-is-an-island)
- [Poem Hunter](https://www.poemhunter.com/poem/no-man-is-an-island/)
- [Quartz](https://qz.com/716088/john-donnes-solemn-400-year-old-poem-against-isolationism-is-resonating-with-brits-today/)
- [Mensa for Kids](https://www.mensaforkids.org/read/a-year-of-living-poetically/donne-no-man-is-an-island/).

Such a presentation is ahistorical, unmooring the passage from its context as a devotional work. It also misrepresents Donne's own poetry, which was always closed-form, never free verse using arbitrary line breaks that eschew rhyme and meter. Additionally, the passage lacks the [metaphysical wit](http://vanityfea.blogspot.com/2012/09/metaphysical-wit.html) that is a conspicuous, even defining, feature of Donne's poetry.

So, **when and why did this passage start being considered, presented, and read as poetry?** I suspect that this is a relatively recent development attributable to the proliferation of websites. I'm hoping someone adept at trawling the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org) will, with some research, be able to answer.

Comment: Something similar happened to [the story of Mel](https://www.cs.utah.edu/~elb/folklore/mel.html) as it bounced around the internet.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Independent versifications

The versification of this passage from Donne predates the widespread use of the Internet, as you’ll see from the earliest examples below. Moreover, it looks as though multiple editors have independently decided to format the passage as verse. The evidence for this is that different editors have chosen different ways to break up the passage into lines. We would not expect this to happen if they were copying from some shared source. Here are two  different eight-line versifications:

> No man is an island, entire of itself;
> every man is a piece of the continent, a part of the main.
> If a clod be washed away by the sea,
> Europe is the less, as well as if a promontory were,
> as well as if a manor of thy friend’s or of thine own were:
> any man’s death diminishes me, because I am involved in mankind,
> and therefore never send to know for whom the bell tolls;
> it tolls for thee.
>
> <sub>Myrna Grant, ed. (1997) [*Poems for a Good and Happy Life*, p. 104](https://archive.org/details/poemsforgoodhapp00gard/page/84/mode/2up). Garden City: CrossAmerica.</sub>

> No man is an island, entire of itself;
> Every man is a piece of the Continent, a part of the main;
> If a clod be washed away by the sea, Europe is the less,
> As well as if a promontory were,
> As well as if a manor of thy friend’s or of thine own were;
> Any man’s death diminishes me, because I am involved in Mankind;
> And therefore never send to know for whom the bell tolls;
> It tolls for thee.
>
> <sub>Mehmet Basci, ed. (2008). [*World Leaders’ Favourite Poems: a Book of Peace*, p. 7](https://archive.org/details/worldleadersfavo0000unse/page/6/mode/2up). Cardigan: Parthian.</sub>

Two different nine-line versions:

> No man is an island, entire of itself;
> Every man is a piece of the continent, a part of the main.
> If a clod be washed away by the sea, Europe is the less,
> As well as if a promontory were;
> As well as if a manor of thy friend’s or of thine own were;
> Any man’s death diminishes me,
> Because I am involved in mankind.
> And therefore never send to know for whom the bell tolls;
> It tolls for thee.
>
> <sub>Jackie Morris, ed. (2006). [*Barefoot Book of Classic Poems*, p.104](https://archive.org/details/barefootbookofcl00morr/page/103/mode/2up). Cambridge: Barefoot Books.</sub>

> No man is an island, entire of itself;
> Everyman is a piece of the Continent, part of the main;
> If a clod be washed away by the sea,
> Europe is the less;
> As well as if a promontary were;
> As well as if a manor of thy friends, or of thine own were;
> Any man’s death diminishes me, because I am involved in Mankind;
> And therefore, never send to know for whom the bell tolls;
> It tolls for thee.
>
> <sub>Emeka Odumegwu-Ojukwu (1989). *Because I am Involved*, p. 111. Spectrum Books.</sub>

A seven-line version with an excision, identified by Peter Shor in comments:

> No man is an island, entire of itself;
> every man is a piece of the continent,
>     a part of the main;
> … any man’s death diminishes me, because
>     I am involved in mankind;
> and therefore never send to know for whom the bell tolls;
> it tolls for thee.
>
> <sub>Sarah Anne Stuart (1996). [*A Treasury of Poems*, p. 221](https://archive.org/details/treasuryofpoemsc0000unse/page/220/mode/2up). New York: Galahad Books (1999). Ellipsis in original.</sub>

#### Manner of thine own

It is hard to trace the origin of these versifications because available search tools tend not to have any way of searching for line breaks, so that the rare versified versions of Donne’s text are buried among the common prose versions. However, if an editor happens to introduce a corruption at the same time as the versification, then the search tools become much more helpful. Here’s an example of such a corrupted text in the form of a fourteen-line versification:

> No man is an island,
> Entire of itself.
> **Each** is a piece of the continent,
> A part of the main.
> If a clod be washed away by the sea,
> Europe is the less.
> As well as if a promontory were.
> As well as if a **manner** of **thine own**
> Or of **thine friend’s** were.
> Any man’s death diminishes me,
> Because I am involved in mankind.
> **Therefore, send not** to know
> For whom the bell tolls,
> It tolls for thee.
>
> <sub>Deborah Gaye, ed. (2010). [*Of Love and Hope*, p. 152](https://archive.org/details/oflovehope0000unse/page/152/mode/2up). London: Avalanche. Corruptions in bold.</sub>

Some of these changes might be defensible, but “manner” for “manor” and “thine friend” for “thy friend” are just embarrassing mistakes. But this version is rare and so more easily traceable. For example, here it appears in a novel:

> The Sussex shore had been a haunt for smugglers. Towered over by the humps of the Seven Sisters and the knob of Beachy Head, pirates of old had hauled their contraband in through gaps in the cliff. The tales of these buccaneers provided J. M. Barrie with the inspiration for Captain Hook […] Lore like that cluttered Wyatt’s mind as he closed on the lonely cottage ahead. […] His epiphany was to recall John Donne, whose poem took on deeper meaning here at the rim:
>
> No man is an island,
> Entire of itself.
> Every man is a piece of the continent,
> A part of the main.
> If a clod be washed away by the sea,
> Europe is the less.
> As well as if a promontory were.
> As well as if a **manner** of **thine own**
> Or of **thine friend’s** were.
> Any man’s death diminishes me,
> Because I am involved in mankind.
> **Therefore, send not** to know
> For whom the bell tolls,
> It tolls for thee.
>
> <sub>Michael Slade (2008), [*Crucified*, pp. 230–231](https://archive.org/details/crucified00mich/page/230/mode/2up). Sutton: Severn House.</sub>

In the context of a novel, the errors are excusable, since we are told that the protagonist is recalling this “poem” from memory. In particular, the substitution of “manner of thine own” for Donne’s “manor … of thine own” is just the kind of trick that memory can play, because the protagonist’s recollections of stories of smugglers and pirates could have brought to mind a speech from Charles Kingsley’s *Westward Ho!*:

> If it is ordained that thou shouldst advance the ends of the brotherhood by being shark-bitten, or flea-bitten, or bitten by sharpers, to the detriment of thy carnal wealth, or, shortly, to suffer any shame or torment whatsoever, even to strappado and scarpines, thou art bound to obey thy destiny, and not, after that vain Roman conceit, to choose the **manner of thine own** death, which is indeed only another sort of self-murder.
>
> <sub>Charles Kingsley (1855). [*Westward Ho!*, volume 2, p. 268](https://archive.org/details/westwardhoorvoya02kin/page/268/mode/2up). Cambridge: Macmillan.</sub>

On the Internet, this corruption can be traced using the Wayback Machine to [this capture in July 2005](https://web.archive.org/web/20050703080558/http://www.vibrationdata.com/inspirational_poems.htm), and on Google Books to [*A Purpose for Life: Service* (2005) by Alexander Zax](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/A_Purpose_for_Life/RCzVjMtHPGYC?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PT95). Whether one of these is the original of the corrupted text, or whether both are copying from some yet older shared source, is impossible for me to say.

Comment: Thanks! This addresses the *when* part pretty comprehensively. Any speculations as to *why*? The passage gains nothing by being relineated as verse; one might argue both that it’s better as prose, and that it misrepresents Donne’s actual poetry.

Comment: @verbose: this is pure speculation on my part, but by representing a prose passage as poetry, the beauty of the writing is emphasized. The same thing has been done for the ["poem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_they_came...): *First they came for the Communists //
And I did not speak out //
Because I was not a Communist ...*

Comment: Conversely, in his novels David Mitchell likes hiding rhyming poetry in prose (removing the line breaks and any punctuation that hints it is poetry) and seeing whether anybody notices.

Comment: And from 1989, [in Google snippet view](https://www.google.com/books/edition/New_Breed/5F8uAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22no%20man%20is%20an%20island%22) (*New Breed*, Vol. 1, Issues 20-24). To see it, at least on my browser, search for "no man is an island" in the page this takes you to ... the link replaces the quotation marks with html code that Google books doesn't recognize.

Comment: @PeterShor James Thurber does the same thing, disguising poetry as prose, although his writing is quite stylised anyway.

Comment: @PeterShor I actually think both the Donne passage and the Neimöller one read better as prose. My understanding is that the latter is not even a quotation or translation, it’s just a rendition of sentiments Neimöller often expressed.

Comment: @verbose: looking at [German Wikipedia,](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Niem%C3%B6ller) it seems to say (my German is really bad) that Neimöller said these words in several different ways in various speeches. But he eventually settled on an "official version":

Comment: Als die Nazis die Kommunisten holten, habe ich geschwiegen; ich war ja kein Kommunist.
Als sie die Sozialdemokraten einsperrten, habe ich geschwiegen; ich war ja kein Sozialdemokrat.
Als sie die Gewerkschafter holten, habe ich geschwiegen; ich war ja kein Gewerkschafter.
Als sie mich holten, gab es keinen mehr, der protestieren konnte.“

Comment: Google translate renders this as: “When the Nazis took the Communists, I was silent; I wasn't a communist.
When they locked up the Social Democrats, I was silent; I wasn't a Social Democrat.
When they called the trade unionists, I was silent; I wasn't a trade unionist.
When they fetched me, there was no one left to protest." (No mention of Jews in this version, although they were in some other ones.)

Comment: “predates the widespread use of the Internet”…?  The earliest date quoted is 1996, a few years after the [Eternal September](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_September) of 1993, so it doesn't even pre-date widespread use of the Web, let alone the Internet.

Comment: @gidds: Just for you, I added an example from 1989.

Comment: Does OP's question misquote the original text? It uses "thy friend's" and "thine own".  In the various misquotations cited here, "thine friend's" is bolded as an error (which makes sense--it should be "thy friend's"), but so is "thine own".  I thought the convention here was the same as "a" vs "an"--depending on whether the following word starts with a vowel.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Compare the corrupt and original text carefully and you'll see why I bolded "thine own".

Comment: @GarethRees Ah, "thine friend's" jumped out so strongly that I missed the swapped ordering completely, and I'd interpreted your bolded text as "grammatical error" introduced, rather than the broader "misquotation (regardless of type)".

Comment: @GarethRees FWIW I recently realized that a character Will Stanton's 1971 [story](https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=282818488492614&id=197627250345072) refers to "No man is an island" as "a line of poetry." See also [this answer](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/18078/289).